# How to compare two columns with data-type of decimal(15, 2) using "<" operator on sql-server with laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

I tried comparing two columns with data-type decimal(15,2) using laravel and got the error [SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. how do i fix this?? my code below

```
self::where('user_id', $user_id)
      ->where('amount_due','<', 'amount_repaid')
      ->where('loan_type', $loan_type)
      ->get()
```

Comment: @SalmanA I'm saying that the third argument is understood as a literal value in `where()`. For comparing two columns there is [`whereColumn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: @swaggerjacker see @Gserg's comment about using `whereColumn`

Comment: @GSerg thanks the wereColmn() fixed my issue...

Answer (score 1):

using WhereColumn() fixed this issue.